# webserver to use if web app have both internet and non-internet dependent tasks

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I was working on an application where i have two tasks and which are interdependent

1. Fetch some data from external server.
2. Even if the internet gets disconnected can the same webpage call my flask application and call the GPIO?

For now, i am using uwsgi+flask+nginx and in this setup when internet is lost i get lot of errors like

```
Feb 17 18:05:39 raspberrypi uwsgi[1831]: DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 2051) died :( trying respawn ...
Feb 17 18:05:39 raspberrypi uwsgi[1831]: Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 2284)

Upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream
```

And when these errors come, my web application freezes and could not access the underlying flask application. But my application is running on localhost:8080 ip. But i don't know why it freezes when internet is disconnected.

When I disable the internet and host the same system on my mac, it's behaving as expected. I do not understand why it is failing on Raspberry Pi.

Is there anyway i could deploy my flask application even when internet is disconnected i could do the local tasks. By searching online i found out few web-servers

1. Twisted
2. Apache
3. gunicorn
4. Tornado

Please help me with this.

Comment: have you tried to disable the first task to see if the external data fetch may be causing the problem?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem with Raspberry Pi? Can't find it.

Comment: @Ingo Here when i disable the internet and host the same system on my mac, it's behaving as expected. But on raspberry it's behaving differently as mentioned above

Comment: @jsotola Yes, external data fetch is smooth when internet is connected and uwsgi responds properly. But when internet goes down and comes back uwsgi gives the mentioned errors and take 1 min 10 secs to comeback and then it starts hosting the flask application.

Comment: Would you mind adding which distro you're running and whether this also happens when bound to `0.0.0.0:8000`?